# Two developers working concurrently

Tags: project-management

I'm a relatively new developer (two years experience, coming from an apprenticeship) and in my workplace we've only ever had one developer working on a project at a time.
We keep our projects in Microsoft Visual Source Safe and check out files as required, and checking back in when we're done.

However, I've been doing some thinking lately and I'm unsure how we'd work on the same project at the same time? Almost everything has dependencies on some core code and certain base classes. Is there anywhere I can go to read up on concurrent development, or are there any 'techniques' I should be researching?

How do team work on projects together? For background information I'm a .NET developer working mostly with VB.NET and webforms, but am moving onto C# MVC.

### **Edit**

I think what I'm really asking here is about the techniques that should be employed as opposed to the software. I've been tinkering with Git a little and can see the benefits of the system over VSS. I was looking more for help with techniques on a project level that can be employed with concurrent development;

- Should the development of two sections be completed then merged, or should it be more closely worked on together?
- Are there any proven techniques or best practices when it comes to reviewing changes or discussing the next move?
- Are there any books or articles I can read on how to produce a project as a team more efficiently etc?

Comment: While this question is really to broad and open to different opinions I'd suggest to have a look at http://hginit.com/ - it's a nice intro for a modern version control system and will give you an idea what's beyond Visual Source Safe.

Comment: Ignore SourceSafe, and I would ignore git as well. If you've been successfully using VSS then you have none of the problems that make distributed source control systems like git necessary. Look at TFS, which has a free edition as well as an online edition, free for up to 5 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I never used Visual Source Safe, but most chances are a different source control tool called Git (http://git-scm.com/) will make the concurrency better.
2. As the project will grow, you will probably have less collisions - just because there are more files to work on.
3. Try to push back the code more often. No more than 1/day - and hopefully sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Given you are using a Microsoft Stack, does it not make more sense to update yourself and use TFSOnline as an example.  Its far better than its predecessor and everything is fully integrated into your toolset (assuming you use Visual Studio).  There are loads of tools out there but everything I use is free inside a MSDN subscription and it plays nicely together.  I am not saying others aren't ahead of the game but it makes more sense given what you are doing.  Was very surprised to see SourceSafe stil being used.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of SCM(source code management) [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_management),

You can use some kind of program to help you, today the most popular program to this is GIT [Wiki Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), but have many others. Do some research and find out what is better for you.